# ExecuteBatch method return array of value -2 in java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

When I am executing executeBatch method in java, its returning an int array that's fine but the value is -2 of all array elements,

it should be 0 or +ve number that shows number of rows affected,
but its returning -2,

when I checked it in database all updates done successful.
please explain what is the meaning of this -2 and how I find number of rows affected.

Thank,
Deepesh Uniyal

Comment: write the code u have tried....

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The jdbc-spec has the following to say about the return-code of batch-updates:

> ■ 0 or greater — the command was processed successfully and the value is an
>   update count indicating the number of rows in the database that were affected by
>   the command’s execution
>   Chapter 14 Batch Updates 121
>
> ■ Statement.SUCCESS_NO_INFO — the command was processed successfully,
>   but the number of rows affected is unknown

Statement.SUCCESS_NO_INFO is defined as being -2, so your result says everything worked fine, but you won't get information on the number of updated columns.

The oracle-documentation states:

> •
>   For a prepared statement batch, it is not possible to know the number of rows affected in the database by each individual statement in the batch. Therefore, all array elements have a value of -2. According to the JDBC 2.0 specification, a value of -2 indicates that the operation was successful but the number of rows affected is unknown.
>
> •
>   For a generic statement batch, the array contains the actual update counts indicating the number of rows affected by each operation. The actual update counts can be provided only in the case of generic statements in the Oracle implementation of standard batching.
>
> •
>   For a callable statement batch, the server always returns the value 1 as the update count, irrespective of the number rows affected by each operation.

So it seems if you need the update-counts you can't use `PreparedStatement`s but have to fall back to plain `Statement`s.

Comment: Thanks piet.t, but how can I get the number of row affected in batch, according to my process we have to know it, and we are updating more the 600 tps in database so I could not avoid batch processing, pls suggest.

Comment: added some oracle-information. I don't know if this will help, but you could try.

Answer (score 7):

> A value of -2 indicates that a element was processed successfully, but that the number of effected rows is unknown.

[**specs**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch())

Comment: is any way to get the number of affected rows. ?? pls suggetst.

Answer (score 4):

Note that since Oracle 12c this shouldn't be the case anymore:

> For a prepared statement batch, the array contains the actual update counts indicating the number of rows affected by each operation.

See https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/oraperf.htm#JJDBC28773

Answer (score 0):

Standard Update Batching...

```
conn.setAutoCommit(false);

PreparedStatement pstmt = 
          conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO employees VALUES(?, ?)");

pstmt.setInt(1, 2000);
pstmt.setString(2, "Milo Mumford");
pstmt.addBatch();

pstmt.setInt(1, 3000);
pstmt.setString(2, "Sulu Simpson");
pstmt.addBatch();

int[] updateCounts = pstmt.executeBatch();

conn.commit();

pstmt.close();
...
```

You can process the update counts array to determine if the batch processed successfully.

**Error Handling in the Oracle Implementation of Standard Batching**
If any one of the batched operations fails to complete successfully or attempts to return a result set during an executeBatch call, then the processing stops and a java.sql.BatchUpdateException is generated.

After a batch exception, the update counts array can be retrieved using the getUpdateCounts method of the BatchUpdateException object. This returns an int array of update counts, just as the executeBatch method does. In the Oracle implementation of standard update batching, contents of the update counts array are as follows, after a batch is processed:

- For a prepared statement batch, in case of an error in between
  execution of the batch, the executeBatch method cannot return a
  value, instead it throws a BatchUpdateException. In this case, the
  exception itself carries an int array of size n as its data, where n
  is the number of successful record executions. For example, if the
  batch is of size 5 and the error occurs at the 4th record, then the
  BatchUpdateException has an array of size 3 (3 records executed
  successfully) and each item in the array represents how many rows
  were affected by each of them.
- For a generic statement batch or callable statement batch, the update
  counts array is only a partial array containing the actual update
  counts up to the point of the error. The actual update counts can be 
  provided because Oracle JDBC cannot use true batching for generic and
  callable statements in the Oracle implementation of standard update
  batching.

For example, if there were 20 operations in the batch, the first 13 succeeded, and the 14th generated an exception, then the update counts array will have 13 elements, containing actual update counts of the successful operations.

You can either commit or roll back the successful operations in this situation, as you prefer.

In your code, upon failed processing of a batch, you should be prepared to handle either -3 or true update counts in the array elements when an exception occurs. For a failed batch processing, you will have either a full array of -3 or a partial array of positive integers.