# Preparedstatement execute batch return value -2 not inserting values to DB

Tags: java

I am doing a preparedStatement.executeBatch(), i am expecting a row to be added in DB. but it is not inserting properly. It is returning -2 values (as this means transaction success, but it is not sure about the number of records inserted). My code is like below.

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
preparedStatement=con.prepareStatement(query);
preparedStatement.setObject(1, <<value>>);
preparedStatement.addBatch();
insertCnt=preparedStatement.executeBatch(); //this returns -2
preparedStatement.close();
```

Comment: If its only 1 row , why not use `executeUpdate` ?

Comment: Don't forget to `commit`.

Comment: please check following link where same question was asked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022175/executebatch-method-return-array-of-value-2-in-java